# How should I care for a bonsai Bouganvillea?

Tags: trees, bonsai

I just received a bonsai tree as a gift for Mother's Day and it's losing its leaves. I found the insert information card which says the type of bonsai is "Bougainvillea"

At first I had the bonsai facing east & lots of leaves fell, then I read I should leave the tree outside but the leaves continued to fall so I brought the tree back inside and placed it on a window sill facing south. I should also note that I live in the Poconos.

The leaves seem to be OK but I was wondering if I should trim all the dead leaves off & hope that they come back next season?

[image]

The bonsai continues to lose leaves. I'm worried it will die.
Please advise.

Comment: Hi @Diane. You can click the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it to add more information. Please don't post updates to the question in the box marked "Your Answer". Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: What is the frequency of watering, what area do you live?

Comment: @NiallC. I was watering once a week & I live in the Poconos. Unfortunately, all the leaves have now fallen off the tree.

Comment: Not a bonsai expert but Bougainvilleas like it hot and they like direct sun. I live in Tucson, AZ, where we grow them on the south sides of brick walls and they often still freeze in the winter. I'm guessing by now it has died.

Answer (score 4):

Bougainvilleas are a tough drought resistant plant that likes full sun.  When sunlight levels drop, it can drop its leaves.  When this has happened it's recommended to then put the plant into storage watering it a couple of times a month until summer arrives again when it should be put out under the full sun.

They are pretty tough.  My decades old bougainvillea was cut to the ground by accident a year ago, and has regrown from the ground.  So, your plant may survive if you haven't already tossed it.